# How do I decode NSData in php script?

Tags: php, ios, swift, base64

I encoded the body in base64, but I can only pass it as NSData, and PHP will only decrpyt the string. How do I decrypt NSData in php?

Swift code

```
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    let encode = bodyData.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!;
    let crypt = encode.base64EncodedDataWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
    request.HTTPBody = crypt
```

PHP code

```
$postVarUser = base64_decode($_POST["usernamedata"]);
$postVarPass = base64_decode($_POST["passworddata"]);
echo $_POST["usernamedata"];//prints nil
echo $_POST["passworddata"];//prints nil
```

Answer (score 2):

As you are receiving bytes, you should receive them using `php://input`, like so:

```
// Get data from POST
$dataEnc = file_get_contents('php://input');
// Decode data
$dataDec = base64_decode($dataEnc);
// Get username
$username = $dataDec["usernamedata"];
echo($username);
```

This should work if the object has been constructed correctly prior to encoding.

Comment: I made the changes on the php script, but is this correct on the ios end? http://puu.sh/p5d6S/5b9314dc30.png

Answer (score 0):

`NSData` is just a bunch of bytes.  If you set the HTTPBody to that, you can't use `$_POST` on the PHP side to treat it as key/values before you decode it.

I don't know PHP, but from googling, it looks like you want `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA`, Try: `base64_decode($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);`